# In scala not declared value has no error. How does it works?

Tags: scala

Hi I'm newbie in scala.

when I write the below code, Even I didn't declared variable y, but it is allowed.

```
object exercise {
  def fixedPoint(f: Double => Double)(firstGuess: Double) = {
  //some code
  }

  def sqrt(x: Double) = fixedPoint(y => x / y)(1) //No error. weird...
}
```

I don't understand how does it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare `f: Double => Double`, it means that function `f` will take `Double` as input parameter and will return `Double` as output. So, when you pass `y => x / y` function, y here is of type Double and `x/y`(output) is of type double.

It is not giving any compiler error because compiler can infer the type based on type of function fixedPoint expects.

Comment: See [link](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/passing-function-to-function-argument-anonymous) to get more insight into passing function as argument.

Comment: gotcha! I understand

Answer (score 2):

> I didn't declared variable y

Actually, you did.

This ...

```
y => ...
```

... translates into, "Here's a function that takes a single argument. I'm going to call that argument `y`."

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you have a look for [How to use function literals (anonymous functions) in Scala](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-functional-literals-anonymous-functions-in-scala).

In the post, it use a simple example `(i: Int) => i % 2 == 0` to act as a function literals, and pass it to the function `filter`. And see follows:

> Because the Scala compiler can infer from the expression that i is an Int, the Int declaration can be dropped off: `val evens = x.filter(i => i % 2 == 0)`

Then, this is exactly the situation in your post for `y => x / y`, the `Double` was dropped off in your code as scala compiler can infer from the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer this question let me modify your code as:

```
object exercise {
  def fixedPoint(f: Double => Double)(firstGuess: Double) = {
    f(firstGuess)  //call the function in f with the curried parameter
  }

  def sqrt(x: Double) = fixedPoint(y => x / y)(1) //No error. weird...
}
```

I have added a line to call function `f` (which takes `Double` and returns `Double`) with `firstGuess` parameter.

> ```
>     f(firstGuess)  //call the function in f with the curried parameter
> ```

Let's see what what `sqrt` function is all about

```
def sqrt(x: Double) = fixedPoint(y => x / y)(1)
```

It takes a `x` and invokes `fixedPoint` with `y => x/y` and `1`

now your `y` is `firstGuess` parameter (as per modified code) and `x` is the `sqrt` parameter.